# Oracle date coding returning min date value

Tags: oracle, date, min

I have a table returning 2 rows with the same data on including a start date which is the same for both rows in question, there is an update date column that is slightly different per row. How do I find the one closest to the start date. 
E.g.

Date 1   27/01/2014
Date 2   27/01/2015 07:39:30
Date 2 row 2  27/01/2015 11:30:51

There are plenty of other columns involved but these are the relevant ones, how would you return the row that is the earliest date? so row containing 07:39:30 
I have tried using the min function but it is returning both rows.

Comment: This is a really vague question so I'll give a vague answer... you could make it work by doing a subselect of the rows with the min start date, and then selecting the row with the earliest update date in that set.

Comment: What is the **data type** of the date column? Are you sure it is `DATE` data type or is it something else?

Comment: please add to your post the structure of your table, and format the sample data to be understandable.

Answer (score 0):

> how would you return the row that is the earliest date? so row containing 07:39:30 I have tried using the min function but it is returning both rows.

In **Oracle**, a **DATE** data type has both **date** and **time** portions. Any date function applied on the date column will give you the perfect result, unless you have a **design issue**. Most frequent design problems are related to **storing date** values as **string**.

For example,

Among the below mentioned date values,

- `27/01/2015 07:39:30`
- `27/01/2015 11:30:51`

The **`MIN`** function on the above mentioned date values will return `27/01/2015 07:39:30`.